# Angular Promise function with a for loop isn't working as expected

Tags: angular, while-loop, promise

I'm struggling with few lines of code in Angular. I have a function that loops through an array of Countries, and for each country it runs an http-request. Every http request result, will be pushed to an array.

I want the function to log the full array, only when all the While-Loop is over, but I can't get it working.
Despite the whole for-loop is taking 10 or more seconds to fetch all the data for the different countries, the console.log command is executed immediately

I tried with Array.foreach loop method as well, but makes no difference.

here's the function code

```
loadData() {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var tmp:any = [];
        var i=0;
        while (i<this.CountryList.length) {
            // for each country in country list, fetch data from http json api
            this.server.readAll(this.CountryList[i].Country).subscribe(res => {        
            tmp = res        
        
            //filter element in res and populate the array I need to return
            tmp.forEach(element => {
            var retrievedDate: Date = new Date(element.deviceretrievedTstamp)          
                if (retrievedDate > this.FourDXBegin) {            
                    this.finalArray.push(element)                                                     
                    }          
                })
            })
            i=i+1;
        }      
        resolve()
    })
    return promise;
}
```

and this is the function called in the ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadData().then(()=> console.log("Final Array is full"))
}
```

Final Array is full always show in the console as soon as ng-init

Answer (score 0):

the problem is inside your while loop, you subscripe to an observable but do not wait until it is resolved.

```js
// for each country in country list, fetch data from http json api
this.server.readAll(this.CountryList[i].Country).subscribe(res => {
    // callback function
    // doing something with 'res'
})
i = i + 1;
```

the callback function within you subscribed to will be executed sometime in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle this case with Promises you can try

```
    loadData() {

    const promises = this.CountryList.map(({Country})=> this.server.readAll(Country).toPromise());

    return Promise.all(promises)
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadData().then((response)=>{
        const parsedData = response.reduce((result, item)=>{
            const temp = item.filter((element)=>new Date(element.deviceretrievedTstamp)>this.FourDXBegin)
            result.concat(temp);
            return result;
        },[]);
    
        console.log('Final array', parsedData)
```

but I believe this will be better

```
    loadData() {
    return forkJoin(this.CountryList.map(({Country})=> this.server.readAll(Country))
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadData().subscribe((response)=>{
        const parsedData = response.reduce((result, item)=>{
            const temp = item.filter((element)=>new Date(element.deviceretrievedTstamp)>this.FourDXBegin)
            result.concat(temp);
            return result;
        },[]);

        console.log('Final array', parsedData)

}
```